# Vectorized addition of vectors with sparse differences

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, vectorization

I represent vectors with a lot of repeated elements by a index-vector and a value vector so that the index-vector contains the indices of value-changes in the vector and the value-vector contains the value at those indices. 
For instance: `[1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 4, 4]` is represented by index-vector `[0, 3, 5]` and value-vector `[1, 7, 4]`.

I have an algorithm for adding two such vectors, but it feels like it should be possible to do it in a cleaner and faster way. 
Are there any better ways to do this in python/numpy?

The current algorithm combines the diffs of the two arrays and does a cumsum in the end. But this requires alot of cleanup to make sure the there aren't any duplicated index-entries, and no consecutive equal values.

```
import numpy as np

class SparseVector:
    def __init__(self, indices, values, sanitize=False):
        self._indices = np.asanyarray(indices)
        self._values = np.asanyarray(values)
        if sanitize:
            self._sanitize()

    def __add__(self, other):
        all_indices = np.r_[self._indices, other._indices]
        args = np.argsort(all_indices, kind='mergesort')
        diffs = np.r_[self._values[0], np.diff(self._values),
                      other._values[0], np.diff(other._values)]
        diffs = diffs[args]
        return self.__class__(all_indices[args], np.cumsum(diffs), True)

    def _sanitize(self):
        # Remove duplicate indexes
        index_diffs = np.ediff1d(self._indices, to_end=1)
        changes = index_diffs != 0
        self._indices = self._indices[changes]
        self._values = self._values[changes]

        # Remove duplicated values
        value_diffs = np.ediff1d(self._values, to_begin=1)
        changes = value_diffs != 0
        self._indices = self._indices[changes]
        self._values = self._values[changes]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.all(self._indices == other._indices)\
            and np.all(self._values == other._values)


a = SparseVector([0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10], [0, 10, 5, 8, 10, 11])
b = SparseVector([0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10], [3, 2, 9, 7, 11, 10])
assert a+b == SparseVector([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9],
                           [3, 13, 12, 14, 17, 15, 17, 21])
```

Comment: ... use `scipy.sparse`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, do you mean by storing the value-diffs in a sparse matrix, or do they have  a structure for storing continous areas directly (can't find it)?

Comment: Those are not really sparse vectors, because sparse means most of the values are 0, this is something else.